# Update all data in a table without affecting ID(PK)

Tags: update

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I have a table with 4846 customer records. The PK is called ID and spans from record 40003 to 79870.
This numbers are used a other tables to hold info about user orders, for example.
Within the table there's a decimal field that stores the amount of credit each user is entitled (CustomerCredit).

Now, the problem is I cant manage to come a up to a way of updating all of the CustomerCredit records without affecting the ID field... The only information that needs to change is the credit amount per each user.

Any clue will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully clear regarding where you get the new `CustomerCredit` value but an SQL update should never change ID unless you explicitly tell it to.

`UPDATE [table] SET CustomerCredit = 100.0 WHERE ID = [customer-id-to-update]`

or setting all records to the same value, just omit the `WHERE`

`UPDATE [table] SET CustomerCredit = 100.0`

Comment: Uhmmm yeah. I'll explain what happened.
So the database went through a massive process generated by an outdated Access frontend, this worked almost fine for all the remaining table other that this specific one. So now the Amounts reflect the credits from before the update process.
Now I need to update all 4846 records credit amount.

Initially I thought of truncating the table and adding all the correct information, that's not an option since theres a PK that doesnt start on 1.

Comment: Based on the question, `WHERE ID BETWEEN 4003 AND 79870` would be the best clause.

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm missing because according to this I could update every CustomerCredit amount to a fixed amount, such as 100, but there all different I would need to query 4648 times.

Comment: Nah, the UPDATE statement will update all records unless you restrict it with a WHERE clause, like the one @JohnM suggested. 

Should all CustomerCredit amounts be the same in the end? If not, where is the source data coming from for the new CustomerCredit values?

Comment: UPDATE Customers
SET CustomerCredit = 100.00
WHERE ID BETWEEN 40000 AND 79870

Will let every user with credit 100.00

Comment: Yeah, that looks about right. Any ID below 40000 or above 79870 will be untouched. The rest should end up with 100.00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update each of the 4846 with a different CustomerCredit value, you will have to issue one query for each of the IDs:

> UPDATE [table] SET CustomerCredit = [credit-of-customer-with-id-40003] WHERE ID = 40003
>   ...
>   UPDATE [table] SET CustomerCredit = [credit-of-customer-with-id-79870] WHERE ID = 79870

Depending on how you have access to the CustomerCredit of each customer, you might be able to generate the 4846 queries...

Comment: The overhead for this is totally unnecessary - see my comment on fredli74's answer for using `BETWEEN`

Comment: This only works if the CustomerCredit has to be updated to the same value for each customer. As indicated in the question, there is a different CustomerCredit value for each customer.

Comment: Oops, I totally glossed over that part :)

Comment: OMG, I just started feeling the brain shakes that I experience when I predict a massive amount of time in a small task.